# Is there a shortcut in VS for "next statement in current thread"?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

When debugging multi threaded .NET apps in VS (2008) I frequently want to step through code. When I press F10 quite often I find VS jumping to a statement in another thread. Its really confusing and always throws me off.

I can work around it by chucking in a million breakpoints.

Is there a cleaner way of asking VS debugger to go to the next statement in the current thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Robbins, an authority on Windows debugging, [just posted a macro](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/07/17/automatically-freezing-threads-brrrrr.aspx) that allows you to freeze and thaw threads in bulk in VS 2008.

This certainly makes things much easier. Thread inter-dependencies may end up causing issues, nonetheless this is a workable solution most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

Probably a much simpler way would be to Freeze any thread that you're not interested in tracing (right click in the Threads window). This may mean a little manual manipulation for you, and won't accurately represent thread interaction, but you won't jump from one thread to the next.

Comment: This works, but has its limitations, in particular it falls apart when your next step depends on other threads doing stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Alan McBee.  I think in VS 2010 they're adding a 'freeze all threads except this one' command, which will make this easier, too.  But I think there's no other way to achieve your goal (e.g. must either freeze threads or set breakpoints).